# chain 2 dropdown lists with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

i want to have 2 dropdown menu's chained to each other so the 2nd dropdown only show options with the value that match 1st dropdown.

here is my html

```
<select class="form-control" id="color">                
    <option value=""> choose options </option>                
    <option value="27">Blomme</option>
    <option value="26">Grøn</option>
    <option value="28">Syren</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="size">             
    <option value=""> choose options </option>
    <option value="27">XL </option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="28">S</option>
</select>
```

i have tried this http://appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects, but i can't get it to work :/

**UPDATE:**

with the plugin my code was:

```
<select class="form-control" id="color">                
    <option value=""> choose options </option>                
    <option value="27">Blomme</option>
    <option value="26">Grøn</option>
    <option value="28">Syren</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="size">             
    <option value=""> choose options </option>
    <option class="27" value="27">XL</option>
    <option class="26" value="26">L</option>
    <option class="26" value="26">L</option>
    <option class="26" value="26">L</option>
    <option class="28" value="28">S</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#size').chainedTo('#color');
</script>
```

Comment: why not show us what you had with the plugin? and maybe we can answer why it wasn't working for you...

Comment: missing quotes on the class properties in the second list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `class=value` for the second `<select>` values . Check
[**Working DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KmXvkhNU8dcEueiw8ksZ?p=preview)

```
<select class="form-control" id="color">

   <option value="">choose options</option>
    <option value="27">Blomme</option>
    <option value="26">Grøn</option>
    <option value="28">Syren</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="size">
    <option value="">choose options</option>
    <option value="27" class="27">XL</option>
    <option value="26" class="26">L</option>
    <option value="26" class="26">L</option>
    <option value="26" class="26">L</option>
    <option value="28" class="28">S</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: i had forgot the **$(function(){**
 $("#size").chained("#color");
**});**

Answer (score 1):

HTML>

```
<select class="form-control" id="color">                
    <option value=""> choose options </option>                
    <option value="27">Blomme</option>
    <option value="26">Grøn</option>
    <option value="28">Syren</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="size">             
    <option value=""> choose options </option>
    <option value="27">XL </option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="28">S</option>
</select>
```

JQuery>

```
$("#color").change(function(){
    $("#size option").css({"display":"block"});
    var val=$("#color").find(":selected").val();

    $("#size option[value!="+val+"]").css({"display":"none"});


});
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE, and if you select the 2nd dropdown and use arrow key on keyboard you can still choose the options that ain't displayed.

Comment: yep otherwise this would be way better because it dont need plugin

Comment: I have written another ansewer try...working nice @user3464204

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
 <select class="form-control" id="color">                
        <option value=""> choose options </option>                
        <option value="27">Blomme</option>
        <option value="26">Grøn</option>
        <option value="28">Syren</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="size">             
        <option value=""> choose options </option>
        <option value="27" class="27">XL </option>
        <option value="26" class="26">L</option>
        <option value="26" class="26">L</option>
        <option value="26" class="26">L</option>
        <option value="28" class="28">S</option>
    </select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $("#size").chained("#color");
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/g5BCL/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$('#color').change(function() {
     var opt1 = this.value;
    $('#size').children('option').each(function () {

      if(this.value != opt1 && this.value != "")
      {
        this.remove();
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1000% working

HTML>

```
<select class="form-control" id="color">                
    <option value=""> choose options </option>                
    <option value="27">Blomme</option>
    <option value="26">Grøn</option>
    <option value="28">Syren</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="size">             
    <option value=""> choose options </option>
    <option value="27">XL </option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="26">L</option>
    <option value="28">S</option>
</select>
```

JQuery>

```
$alloption=$("#size").html();
$("#color").change(function(){

     $("#size").html($alloption);

    var val=$("#color").find(":selected").val();

    $("#size option[value!="+val+"]").remove();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can help you.

```
$("#color").change(function(){
  var selected_value = $(this).val();
  $('#size option').each(function() {
    var vl = $(this).val();
    if(vl == selected_value){
      $(this).show();
    } else{
      $(this).hide();
    }
 });

});
```